# Error building wheel for torch-sparse (error installing pytorch geometric)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I came across this error where installing pytorch geometric gives tons of errors, particularly on google colab.
This error pops out from time to time and it has to do with the torch and cuda versions. So far, the solutions on the internet didn't work for me. Usually concerns an "error building wheel for torch-sparse".

I have seen many people with this error still unsolved on the internet, so I will post the solution as an answer to this question. Hopefully will save some hours to all of you!

Comment: An explanation of this query is already given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71174832

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following script to install pytorch geometric

```
import torch
try:
    import torch_geometric
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    TORCH = torch.__version__.split("+")[0]
    CUDA = "cu" + torch.version.cuda.replace(".","")
!pip install torch-scatter     -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-{TORCH}+{CUDA}.html
!pip install torch-sparse      -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-{TORCH}+{CUDA}.html
!pip install torch-geometric
import torch_geometric
```